# Error Laravel insert two record same into Mysql

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, mysql-error-1064

I have a problem when unsing Laravel. I insert one page into Mysql but in Mysql show two record same.

Router:

```
Route::post('pages','Admin\Pages@adds');
```

Controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class Pages extends Controller
{
    //
    public function adds(Request $request)
    {
        $pages = \App\Page::adds($request);
        return redirect('admin/pages');
    }
}
```

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Page extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'page';

    public static function adds($request)
    {
        $pages = new Page;
        $pages->title = $request->input('title');
        $pages->content = $request->input('body');
        $pages->status = $request->input('status');
        $pages->timeupdate = time();
        $pages->save();
        return 1;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think ```return redirect('admin/pages')``` in ```Pages ``` controller ```adds()``` method is creating this duplication issue. Can you please comment it and try inserting record again?

Comment: Why is the question tagged with `mysql-error-1064`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Page extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'page';

}
```

Controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Page;

class Pages extends Controller
{
    //
    public function adds(Request $request)
    {
        $pages = new Page;
        $pages->title = $request->input('title');
        $pages->content = $request->input('body');
        $pages->status = $request->input('status');
        $pages->timeupdate = time();
        $pages->save();
        //return 1;
        return redirect('admin/pages');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you implement above code ? 
If yes , then what's your output?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

**Model**:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Page extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'page';

}
```

**Controller**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Page;

class Pages extends Controller
{
    public function adds(Request $request)
    { 

      $data = $request->all();
      $pages = \App\Page::create($data);
      return redirect('admin/pages');
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  What did you change?  Why?  How will this help?